# Screenshots of mouseover popups

Tags: windows, screenshot

I'm having trouble capturing screenshots with mouseover popups showing. I'm using Win 8.1 at the moment.

There's lots been written here, but none of the solutions work for me. These include the snipping tool, Ctrl+PrtScn, Alt+PrtScn, and just plain old Windows key+PrtScn.

This may be impossible to do - in fact, I resorted to using a phone camera, which got me some nice Moire lines and a poor image. But if you have solved this one, please share.

Paul

Australia

Comment: So if you push printscreen, it does not coppy the img?

Comment: No. Touch any key and the popup vanishes.

Comment: Last question.what language are you using vb.net or c#?and is it winforms?and with popup you mean tooltips?

Comment: This is plain Outlook in Windows, and I mean the popups you get when you mouseover a link/URL.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer to this question here. What worked for you? @calder

Comment: I don't know if this will help anyone, but on my Surface Laptop 3 I found that when trying to press Ctrl+Printscreen or Alt-Printscreen the popup would vanish before capture. BUT Fn-Printscreen captured the popup fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got a way to do this.

I used the Problem Steps Recorder - got a few screens that included the mouse pointer and the popup. Perfect for what I want.

Paul

Comment: Seems like you have to trigger the screen grab. I don't know which did it, but I was able to capture the tooltip I needed after right-clicking, hitting a letter key or ctrl.

Answer (score 45):

This is old but I'm writing the answer here just in case I need it in the future. This can be easily done using Snipping Tool which already comes with Windows.

Snipping Tool has a Delay button that let you set the delay between 1-5 seconds. What this does is after you click New, it waits 1-5 seconds before freezing the screen and letting you select a rectangle. All you need to do is: set the delay --> click on New --> Hover or right-click to open the tooltips/popup menu and wait for the screen the freeze. Snipping Tool will freeze the screen with the tooltips still available.

Comment: For those stuck on Windows 7, the snipping tool has no Delay button but does have a keyboard shortcut. If you have the snipping tool open and selected (but with no snip in progress - ie. cancel button greyed out), you can mouse over your tooltip/popup and then hit ctrl+prtsc without losing it. This blog post has more information: https://ratborg.blogspot.com/2015/06/use-snipping-tool-in-delay-mode.html

Comment: It got the tooltip popup, but not the cursor.

Comment: I can't see any 'delay' option on the snipping tool